# Fastest way to check for unique entries in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
first | last
John  | Smith
Bob   | dfgdf
John  | fggf
John  | Smith
```

And I want to run a query that will return only rows that have a unique last name for each first name. So only Bob dfgdf should be returned. Currently, I'm grouping twice and checking if count = 1, but is there a faster way?

`SELECT first FROM (
   SELECT first, last FROM table1 GROUP BY first, last
)as t1 GROUP BY first HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
SELECT first
FROM table1
GROUP BY first
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT last);
```

### Demo

This just retains only first names whose record count is coincident with the count of distinct last names, which would imply that each first name maps to a distinct last name.

**Edit:**

If you want all columns from all matching rows, then you may try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT first
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY first
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT last)
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.first = t2.first;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to also include the last name in the select or would I need to do an outer query that selects first and last where first is in the inner query?

Comment: @st2tas I gave you an option for retrieving all columns from all matching rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Grouping by last makes no sense to me here, and also your having trick is out of place.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
SELECT first
FROM table1
GROUP BY first
HAVING MIN(last) = MAX(last);
```

Actually, this should make use of an index on `table1(first, last)`.

If the above doesn't use the index, then I would expect the fastest way to be:

```
select distinct on (first) first
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 tt1 where tt1.first = t1.first and tt1.last <> t1.last)
order by first;
```

This can make use of an index on `table1(first, last)` for performance.